# What are some practical uses of Lua in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, lua

I see many text editors for Mac OS X that support Lua syntax highlighting, but I have yet to see an example of Lua being used in action in the actual Operating System.

How is Lua being used practically?

Comment: Sorry. :( I wanted it to stand out in the title and I guess that just carried over into the question. :P Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

World of Warcraft addons use Lua, among many other games. Some games use it as a "private" scripting language that isn't available to users.

Here are some other [uses of Lua](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaUses).

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Cortex Command](http://www.datarealms.com/) (an **awesome** indie game) uses it as a scripting language, for one.